# Windows 10+ CMD adding space after initial command

Tags: windows, windows-10, logging

Noticed last week from our SIEM logs that windows command line is adding an additonal space after the initial command. Examples:

- `ping 1.1.1.1` turns into `ping  1.1.1.1`
- `net user bob /do` turns into `net  user bob /do`

I don't know when this started to occur, I have found nothing online from anyone else regarding this. The issue of course is if you're searching through logs and you're looking for a specific command and you're putting one space, you will not find it. This is not occurring with PowerShell, the exact same command logs properly with no additional space.

Can anyone else verify this within their environment? Is this just an issue that recently started happening in Windows 10?

Comment: How is CMD being run? From a .bat file? Show the contents of that file. Also consider if Unicode [Space] is being interpreted as two spaces.

Comment: Whichever software is generating the commands or logging them is the one adding the blanks.